# Why does my string have a colon appended when outputted to HTML

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-forms

When I add a parathesis to the following label string it's printed in my HTML with a colon appended to it:

```
question_3 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=QUESTION_3_CHOICES,
widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label = mark_safe('Which of 
these styles do you like? (choose multiple)'))
```

The label in my form gets outputted like this in my HTML:

```
 Which of these styles do you like? (choose multiple):
```

When I remove '(choose multiple)', it prints correctly like this with no colon appended:

```
Which of these styles do you like?
```

I tried converting all the text to unicode before using mark_safe by doing this:

```
question_3 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=QUESTION_3_CHOICES,
widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label = mark_safe('Which of 
these styles do you like? (choose multiple)').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

But that didn't fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is "Why this happens?" then have a look at the source of BaseForm class (at django.forms.forms.BaseForm):

```
if self.label_suffix:
    if label[-1] not in ':?.!':
        label += self.label_suffix
label = bf.label_tag(label) or ''
```

By default the BaseForm constructor sets label_suffix=':'.

How to fix? Try passing label_suffix when initializing your form, most likely it inherits from BaseForm.